# Is it possible that JNI function return integer or boolean?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

**JAVA Code**

```
boolean b = invokeNativeFunction();
int i = invokeNativeFunction2();
```

**C code**

```
jboolean Java_com_any_dom_Eservice_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    bool bb = 0;
    ...
    return // how can return 'bb' at the end of the function?
}

jint Java_com_any_dom_Eservice_invokeNativeFunction2(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    int rr = 0;
    ...
    return // how can return 'rr' at the end of the function?
}
```

Is it possible that JNI function return integer or boolean? If yes, How I can do that?

Comment: Your C code method signatures must agree precisely with the generated headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just return the value directly.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_demojni_Sample_intMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
    jint value) {
    return value * value;
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_demojni_Sample_booleanMethod(JNIEnv* env,
    jobject obj, jboolean unsignedChar) {
    return !unsignedChar;
}
```

There is a map relation between Java primitive type and native type, reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp9502).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do some static casts:

```
return static_cast<jboolean>(bb);

return static_cast<jint>(rr);
```

In my copy of `jni.h` `jint` is defined as an `int32_t`, and `jboolean` is defined as a `uint8_t`. The internal representations of `true` and `false` are the same in C++ and Java (at the VM level) AFAIK (i.e. 0==false, 1==true).

You can of course add some sanity checks if you want to, e.g.:

```
assert(numeric_limits<jint>::is_signed == numeric_limits<decltype(rr)>::is_signed &&
       numeric_limits<jint>::min() <= numeric_limits<decltype(rr)>::min() &&
       numeric_limits<jint>::max() >= numeric_limits<decltype(rr)>::max());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method signatures might be wrong...

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

If you'll notice a few things:

1)  the addition of `JNIEXPORT` and  `JNICALL` around methods..
2)  the to `j<object>` type of arguments to be returned.

I think you need to mofidy your int example to:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_any_dom_Eservice_invokeNativeFunction2(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    jint rr = 99;
    ...
    return rr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java class change return type to primitive - boolean. In jni header change return type - jobject to jboolean, and dont generate header again to save changes.